# Three.js: Shader won't compile with gl.MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS textures

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm using Three.js to build a scene in which I want to pack the maximum number of quads into each draw call. On my machine, the limiting factor is the number of textures I can display in each draw call.

What confuses me is that `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)` returns 16, but if I try to pass exactly 16 textures into my `THREE.RawShaderMaterial`, I get the following error:

> THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false
>   gl.getProgramInfoLog ERROR: Implementation limit of 16 active fragment
>   shader samplers (e.g., maximum number of supported image units)
>   exceeded, fragment shader uses 17 samplers

If I pass exactly 15 textures in, the scene renders fine (though a texture is missing of course).

My question is: Does Three.js add an additional texture to each draw call somewhere? If not, does anyone know what might account for this off by one problem? Any help others can offer on this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A stupid question: Are you sure your shader is defining only 16 `sampler2d` objects? If you're extending existing three.js shader code, you may be accidentally inheriting (bad but appropriate phrasing) another `sampler2d` from one of the many texture map uniforms.

Comment: @TheJim01 I'm changing debuggers right now and will check the number of textures received when I pass 15 sampler2d's, though I'm positive my: `textures: {
        type: 'tv',
        value: THIS_ARRAY,
      },` contains exactly 16 elements when the error is thrown

Comment: I'm less concerned with what the three.js object says, and more so with what the GLSL says. For the most part, three.js is pretty good about not including unnecessary shader chunks, but it sounds like there is a stray one in there somewhere in your case.

Comment: @duhaime Have you tried Firefox Shader Editor under developer tools? It lets you read through all your shaders after being compiled, which could be very helpful at finding out exactly what gets added to your GLSL: https://imgur.com/EaRTAVf (I'm sure Chrome has this tool also, but I've never used it)

Comment: @Marquizzo is there a way to see the textures being used by a fragment shader in the FF WebGL tools? It looks like no, but thought I'd ask...

Comment: @duhaime Ah, no. FFox only lets you see the GLSL code. However, the "WebGL Inspector" extension in the Chrome store looks promising! I just checked it out, and it's got a very thorough "Textures" tab with lots of good detail: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webgl-inspector/ogkcjmbhnfmlnielkjhedpcjomeaghda?hl=en-US I just noticed that my current project has a 1x1 texture that seems to come out of nowhere.

Comment: You can add `<script src="https://rawgit.com/greggman/dump-all-the-shaders/master/dump-all-the-shaders.js"></script>` to your page **before** other scripts and hopefully all your shaders will be dumped to the console including the versions passed to the GPU by WebGL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's embarrassing. It turns out I was passing 16 textures to the shader, but I was trying to access `texture2D(textures[16])` and it was this attempt to read from a sampler index > max textures that threw this error.

It's interesting that passing a material array longer than `gl.MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` does not throw an error -- it's trying to access index value > `gl.MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`-1 that throws an error.

Comment: If you declare too many samplers but only access the first 1 the driver (optionally) will optimize out the other samplers (same with any uniforms) so you won't (up to the driver's optimization) get an error for declaring an array with too many samplers if you don't use them. Since it's an array what matters is the highest index you access (for drivers that optimize away unused uniforms).

Comment: @gman amen, thanks very much for your note. By the way, do you happen to know how one can set `GL_POINT_SPRITE_COORD_ORIGIN` (ideally in such a way that Three.js won't reset it)? I planned to post a question but thought you might know, as you've answered a good margin of my gl questions!

Comment: Seems like you should ask a proper question so people can search for the answer?

Comment: @gman Thanks for your note. I asked a question and pailhead pointed out this is in the OpenGL spec but not OpenGL ES 2.0 so I deleted the question, as one can't set this attribute from Three.js or using WebGL

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Does Three.js add an additional texture to each draw call somewhere? If not, does anyone know what might account for this off by one problem?

Yes, most of the materials inject various samplers related to various maps. It can be something as straightforward as an "albedo map" but it could also be a shadow map for example. Use `RawShaderMaterial` if you don't want three to inject stuff.

Comment: Hmmmmmmm, that is really odd I have to admit. Is there any way one could see some live code?

Comment: To confirm, `RawShaderMaterial` should not include any phantom samplers?

Comment: yes, that's right -- only the textures I passed into the RawShaderMaterial were present in the material. I had simply made an indexing error that threw the error above (misleading as that error message is)